# Limit related to prime gaps

Tags: analysis, limits, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-gaps

Let $Gap(n)$ be the smallest  natural number k , such that $ ({k,k+1,...,k+n-1}) $ contains no prime numbers. Such a k obviously exists -  for instance $k = (n+1)!+2$ has the desired property. My question is this: does $Gap(n)$ tend to $(n+1)! + 2$ as n goes to infinity, i .e. does the limit

$$lim \frac{Gap(n)}{(n+1)! + 2}$$ exist and, if so, is it equal to 1?

Comment: Look here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap

Comment: The known smallest prime gaps are much smaller than $n!$. Not sure, whether it has been proven that this continues forever.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5029
Some recent research on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined ${\rm Gap}(n)$ as the smallest composite $k$ beginning a prime gap of size $n$. Currently there is no theorem establishing the true order of magnitude of ${\rm Gap}(n)$. However, we can use [Wolf's conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeGaps.html) in this form:
$$
{\rm Gap}(n) = p(n)+1 \asymp \sqrt{n} \exp(\sqrt{n}) = o(n!).
$$
([The MathWorld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeGaps.html) uses $p(n)$, the smallest prime followed by a prime gap of size $n$.)

Then this limit is zero:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{{\rm Gap}(n)}{(n+1)! + 2} = 
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n} \exp(\sqrt{n})}{(n+1)! + 2} = 0.
$$
So, to the best of our current knowledge, the limit is not equal to 1 as the question suggested.